# Including all specified extensions except a specific file with the extension

Tags: regex, jestjs

I'd like to include all image assets but exclude jquery.svg in my string list. For example,

```
./jquery.svg
./assets/icon.svg
./picture.jpg
./pic.png
./readme.md
```

I like to exclude the first one (./jquery.svg) but include all other files with .svg, .jpg, .png and .md. So the point is including all .svg except jquery.svg.

I tried something like

```
((?!jquery\.svg)|\.svg|\.jpg|\.png|\.md)
```

but didn't work. Could someone help me to make it work?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @cid React.js on Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct regex you need is this,

```
^\.\/(?:(?!jquery\.svg$).)*\.(?:svg|jpg|png|md)$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZmJpm/2)**

Comment: @yfaney I sugggest `^\.\/(?!.*jquery\.svg$).*\.(?:svg|jpg|png|md)$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes Wiktor you're right. That `$` will ensure the string to be rejected is strictly only `./jquery.svg` as something else present after that might still need to be allowed. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Applied your suggestion. Thanks!